# Invalid Cofiguration - yii\base\InvalidConfigException - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

I've just installed Yii2-User module/Dektrium to my Yii2-app-basic application by this command

```
composer require "dektrium/yii2-user:0.9.*@dev"
```

**config/console.php**

```
return [
    .
    .
    'modules' => [
        'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            ],
        ],
    .
    .
]
```

**config/web.php**

```
'components' => [
    .
    .
    /*
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
    */
    'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            ],
    ],
    .
    .
]
```

After that, i run this command `$ php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations` for updating database schema .

But, when i run `http://localhost/mylawsuit/yii/web/index.php?r=user/registration/register` in my browser. It throws error:

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>
> The configuration for the "modules" component must contain a "class"
>   element.

Screenshot of Error

[image]

And, when i'm changing **web.php**

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
    /*
    'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            ],
    ],
```

Typing `http://localhost/mylawsuit/yii/web/index.php?r=user/registration/register` in my browser, it shows

> Not Found (#404)
>
> Page not found.

Screenshot

[image]

I'm not getting where i'm doing mistake. Please help me to rectify.

Comment: Hey @InsaneSkulll, thanku for giving suggestion. I got answer. I wrote modules inside components which was wrong actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Got answer.

I wrote `'modules'=>[...]` inside `'components'=>[...]`, which was wrong.

Now, **config/web.php**

```
$config = [
  'id' => 'basic',
  'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
  'bootstrap' => ['log'],
  'components' => [
   .
   .
   .
   ],
  'modules' => [
    'user' => [
      'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
    ],
  ],
  'params' => $params,
```

Now, it's working fine.

Comment: I was following the instructions at the documentation https://xdsoft.net/jodit/examples/intergration/yii-jodit.html but they not specify where to add the module. Thank you, this work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

If u rewrote user model and ['/user/security/login'] redirecting to '/user/login' with 404, open web config and look for 'urlManager' component.
If you have enblePrettyUrl on, look on rules. 
The problem is there - change it or delete.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer is not very clear as it currently is. I would suggest adding some additional code to help the questioner and future users to solve this problem.